# can't write data to .plist in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, plist

I'm trying to write data to .plist file with next method:

```
-(IBAction)saveCity:(id)sender{
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"propTest" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [ array addObject:@"addedTest"];
    if ([array writeToFile:path atomically:NO]){
        NSLog(@"written");
    }
}
```

I have created propTest.plist in advance manually with next content:

[image]

After invoking saveCity: several times I can see that array which I read from propTest.plist contains my strings:

[image]

But actually it contains only what I added manually:

[image]

Could you please help me to find a reason why new Strings are not added to .plist permanently ?

Comment: You can't write to the bundle - this is a readonly package.  You will need to create the plist file in the documents directory once your app starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is - **No, you cannot do this**. iOS application run in sandbox environment wherein you cannot modify the application bundle at run time and therefore you cannot write anything inside `[NSBundle mainBundle]`.

You should use application's documents directory instead. This is how you can do this. Here, just for your knowledge sake, I am copying data from main bundle, appending new details and writing back to documents directory.

```
// Get you plist from main bundle
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"propTest" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Add your object
[array addObject:@"addedTest"];

// Get Documents directory path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistLocation = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"propTest.plist"];

// Write back to Documents directory
[array writeToFile:plistLocation atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Although this is the correct method, you should be using URLs rather than string based file paths.

Comment: @Abizern, Why URLs are better ? Is it a common practice or there are real benefits behind using URLs?

Comment: @YuraVasylenko in the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH7-SW1 under the heading of "_Use Modern File-System Interfaces_" there is the sentence - **When deciding which routines to call, choose ones that let you specify paths using NSURL objects over those that specify paths using strings.**